# TypeError after Vue.use while installation via <script>

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vuejs2

I have to load vue-native-websocket throught script like

```
  <script src="{% static 'js/vue.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/vue-native-websocket.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/vue_components/OrdersCurrent.js' %}"></script>
```

here's my `OrdersCurrent.js`

```
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'wss://localhost/ws/current-orders/1', {
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 5,
  reconnectionDelay: 3000,
  format: 'json',
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#orders-current-app',
  delimiters: ['{*', '*}'],
  created: function () {
    var vm = this;
    this.$options.sockets.onmessage = function (data) {
      vm.messageReceived(data);
    }
  },
  data: {
    message: 'hi Vue!'
  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage: function(event) {
      message = event.target.value;
      this.$socket.sendObj({message: message});
      event.target.value = ''
    },
    receiveMessage: function(websocketMessage) {
      var data = JSON.parse(websocketMessage.data);
      this.messages.push(data.message);
    }
  }
});
```

Looks like `Vue.use` not  working in this case. I got the following error

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmessage' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.js:597
logError @ vue.js:1739
globalHandleError @ vue.js:1734
handleError @ vue.js:1723
callHook @ vue.js:2923
Vue._init @ vue.js:4617
Vue @ vue.js:4716
(anonymous) @ OrdersCurrent.js:8
vue.js:1743 TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmessage' of undefined
    at Vue.created (OrdersCurrent.js:13)
    at callHook (vue.js:2921)
    at Vue._init (vue.js:4617)
    at new Vue (vue.js:4716)
    at OrdersCurrent.js:8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `VueNativeSock.default` instead of `VueNativeSock`. Installation of `vue-native-script` plugin from CDN is undocumented yet.

```
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'wss://localhost/ws/current-orders/1', {
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 5,
  reconnectionDelay: 3000,
  format: 'json',
});
```